# Set global DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, godaddy

I've bought domain on GoDaddy. I've installed BIND server on my CentOS VPS. I set its IP on /etc/resolve.conf on other server, and I was able from that other server to ping domain names that are set in my fwd zone. That tells me that DNS setup is OK. In order to ping domain names without explicitly setting DNS IP, I know that I have to set GoDaddy DNS zone properly. I've read documentation, but everything I get when I try to set custom name server is message: You must enter a registered nameserver.
How to get my nameserver to be registered? Is there something more to be set?

Answer (score 1):

Searching online for the specific error message "You must enter a registered nameserver" produces quite a few hits on forums that suggest that you should:

- Make sure your BIND zone contains an A record for your nameserver itself
- Add the hostname/IP address for your nameserver in GoDaddy settings (see https://uk.godaddy.com/help/editing-your-registered-nameservershosts-3952)

Comment: I've checked, it is. Also, I've already try what you proposed, and now again, and still nothing.

Comment: Then I would suggest speaking to GoDaddy support who can almost certainly investigate the specifics of your issue directly.

Comment: OK, I will try, but I cannot reach their support. It says they have online chat, but there is nowhere link to it. I only see phone number, but I am not interested to speak via phone with them. Perhaps you now more about that?

Comment: Presumably this "other server" you are testing from is not behind the same firewall as your BIND server so it is a fair test of general internet accessibility? If so, sorry, no further ideas.

Comment: It is fair test. These servers are independent and on different locations.

Answer (score 0):

After DNS server is set on your server, go to GoDaddy site and do the following:
1. Manage my domains
2. Choose domain
3. On settings click Manage under Hostnames
4. Add e.g. ns1 and its IP.
5. Go to nameservers and add these hostnames as nameservers.